# How to know if MySQL replication is working?

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.5

I am replicating from a MySQL v 5.5.50 master, to a MySQL v 5.5.46 slave hosted in RDS. I've followed the AWS documentation on how to do this to the letter, got the dump file imported into the slave server and ran the `CALL mysql.rds_set_external_master...` command to begin things a few days ago.

My `SHOW MASTER STATUS;` result is:

```
+---------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| File                | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB |
+---------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| mysql-binlog.000023 | 48684053 |              |                  |
+---------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And my `SHOW SLAVE STATUS \G;` result is:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: [master host IP here]
                  Master_User: [local replication user here]
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-binlog.000023
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 53052514
               Relay_Log_File: relaylog.000007
                Relay_Log_Pos: 81145300
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-binlog.000017
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB:
          Replicate_Ignore_DB:
           Replicate_Do_Table:
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: mysql.rds_sysinfo,mysql.rds_history,mysql.rds_replication_status
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error:
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 1016905328
              Relay_Log_Space: 5695987840
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File:
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File:
           Master_SSL_CA_Path:
              Master_SSL_Cert:
            Master_SSL_Cipher:
               Master_SSL_Key:
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 394467
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error:
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error:
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
             Master_Server_Id: 21033229
1 row in set (0.12 sec)
```

And finally, the only two relevant lines (that aren't SLEEP from my client) visible in `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;` are:

```
*************************** 2. row ***************************
     Id: 207
   User: system user
   Host:
     db: NULL
Command: Connect
   Time: 361292
  State: Waiting for master to send event
   Info: NULL
*************************** 3. row ***************************
     Id: 208
   User: system user
   Host:
     db: NULL
Command: Connect
   Time: 394904
  State: Reading event from the relay log
   Info: NULL
```

I'm trying to confirm whether or not things are actually replicating, because the `Seconds_Behind_Master` value is getting bigger and bigger. However, the `Master_Log_File` value has gone up to match that of the master.

`Exec_Master_Log_Pos` and `Relay_Log_Pos` haven't changed in a long* time. However, `Read_Master_Log_Pos` is growing all the time.

I find no errors in the log files that RDS provides to me, no warnings or errors when the process started.

Is there a way I can tell if there has been some kind of error, and how can I look to recover from it?

(* Not 100% sure on how long that is, but measured in hours, not seconds)

**UPDATE**

I ran a slave stop and then slave start command, and in the log, I got the following:

```
160817 10:39:04 [Note] Slave SQL thread exiting, replication stopped in log 'mysql-binlog.000018' at position 72335184
160817 10:39:04 [ERROR] Error reading packet from server: Lost connection to MySQL server during query ( server_errno=2013)
160817 10:39:04 [Note] Slave I/O thread killed while reading event
160817 10:39:04 [Note] Slave I/O thread exiting, read up to log 'mysql-binlog.000025', position 74416238
160817 10:39:22 [Note] Slave SQL thread initialized, starting replication in log 'mysql-binlog.000018' at position 72335184, relay log '/rdsdbdata/log/relaylog/relaylog.000010' position: 72335333
160817 10:39:22 [Note] Slave I/O thread: connected to master '[replication user]@[server ip]:3306',replication started in log 'mysql-binlog.000025' at position 74416238
```

So nothing untoward there that I can see. The `Seconds_Behind_Master` is still going up and still no individual commands are displaying in my process list etc.

Answer (score 6):

The two `...Running` values say `YES`; that is usually sufficient to say all is well.  However `Seconds_Behind_Master: 394467` is scary.  That 11 hours!

Run a test:  On the Master do `CREATE DATABASE dummy;`, then see if it is there on the Slave.  (You'll probably need to be `root` both times.)

There are situations where `Seconds_Behind_Master` bounces between 0 and some big value.  That is a fluke.  Watch it for a while to see that is the case.

Comment: 394467 seconds is 4.5 days actually, which is the exact time that I began the process. So it says to me that it hasn't done anything?

Comment: I've created a dummy database and so far it hasn't propagated over to the slave server, no. So I have no idea what to do - this is the third time I've tried this (wiping the slave, re-exporting the dump file from the master, importing it to the slave, setting it all up again) and I'm running out of ideas. It's about 60GB of data so it takes a while to do the above!

Comment: Try `SLAVE STOP; SLAVE START;` (on the Slave).  What are the `server_id` values?

Comment: Master'd ID is `21033229` and slave's is `348222988` (Obtained via `SELECT @@server_id;` on each). I ran stop and then start again; still no errors. I'll update my question with the log entries after the restart..

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I never got anywhere with this. In the end, I cancelled it, and used the DMS (Database Migration Service) that AWS provide. So far this seems to be working much better and is almost completed. I've migrated several thousand tables with this, but I had to create the task via the CLI and provide an table mapping file with a wildcard - the Console GUI didn't support doing my thousands of databases.

Answer (score 0):

You may try reading the binlog events in 'mysql-binlog.000018' and see if there is any data corruption or the file didn't close properly.

**Anyway the better suggestion would be to rebuild the slave.**
But you might want to know what does the binlog events contain, for nailing the actual root cause and provide fix. I suspect probably there could be network glitch between Master and Slave Or Slave server would have failed its monitor health for a fraction of a second Or disk would have gone for failure and replaced if under EBS. Since you are in AWS and it is prone for such disasters.